# iphone sdk: How do i add a button to a uitableviewCell?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to add a button to the uitableviewcell and i just can't get it to work any suggestions what i'm doing wrong??

```
checkButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[checkButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];
[checkButton setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10.0 topCapHeight:0.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[checkButton setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10.0 topCapHeight:0.0] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    [cell addSubview:checkButton];

}
NSArray *tempArray = [[exerciseNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectForKey:@"rowValues"];
[cell addSubview:checkButton];
cell.textLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ (%@)", [[tempArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"full"], [[tempArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"short"]];

// Set up the cell...

return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a new instance of the button for every cell, you cannot use a shared instance. A view can be ONLY in one place at a time.

Answer (score 2):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}
UIButton* checkButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[checkButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];
[checkButton setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10.0 topCapHeight:0.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[checkButton setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10.0 topCapHeight:0.0] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[cell addSubview:checkButton];

[checkButton release];

NSArray *tempArray = [[exerciseNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectForKey:@"rowValues"];

cell.textLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ (%@)", [[tempArray  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"full"], [[tempArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"short"]];

// Set up the cell...

return cell;
}
```

This way the button is add on cell & release its own memory so no memory leakage problem

Also you can add button in cell contentview rather than in cell

eg.

```
[cell.contentView addSubview: showButton];
```